# Do laser filaments propagate in a straight line over long distances?

Tags: optics, visible-light, laser, stability, non-linear-optics

In so-called [filament propagation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filament_propagation), a powerful laser beam can propagate through a medium without diffraction.  This occurs because the beam [focuses itself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-focusing) through non-linear optical effects.  Self-focusing is most commonly caused by the optical Kerr effect, in which the refractive index of a material changes due to an applied electric field; however, in extreme conditions, ponderomotive forces and relativistic effects may also become significant.

Under suitable conditions, laser filaments can propagate over very long distances; for example, [one recent study](https://www.osapublishing.org/oe/fulltext.cfm?uri=oe-21-22-26836&id=270436) demonstrated a range of 1 km.  Theoretically, a laser filament could even continue indefinitely in an ideal environment.  However, in real life, the environment is not ideal.  The density of the medium varies slightly, the beam is not perfectly collimated or monochromatic, and so on.

Are laser filaments directionally stable against these small perturbations, or do they tend to veer off by a large angles over very long distances?

---

I found a [couple](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.2799163) of [papers](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.78.033804) on propagation in turbulent regions of air, but both were primarily experimental.  I'm interested in a theoretical understanding as well, to help predict how the system will behave with other wavelengths or materials.  The second paper does discuss [modulational instability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulational_instability), but if I understand correctly, this phenomenon causes breakup of the beam waveform rather than a change in direction.

Comment: I suspect you'll discover a "Random Walk" effect, assuming that the nonuniformity of the medium is properly random in nature.  Compare, e.g., a laser pointing up at an angle so the atmospheric density and composition varies with distance.

Comment: A filament cannot go indefinitely because it loses energy to the medium. The necessary ionization scatters the light and leaves energy in the medium. Also, the filament dynamics would make it pretty hard for it to go on forever, granted that a tailored field might yield a really long travel distance.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know the answer to this question, but I would assume that it might change direction, depending on the dynamics. Overall momentum will be conserved, so there's a chance that the dynamics will affect the k vectors "being expressed" along the filament and veer it a bit, but I guess you would have to figure out how to create the starting k vector ensemble and control its expression along the filament. But this is all just supposition. I suggest [this paper](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0034-4885/70/10/R03)